# I cannot read frontmatter field in my setup

Tags: graphql, gatsby, yaml-front-matter

I have a gatsby setup project and am trying to write custom redirects.
I've managed to get it all to work, by creating `createRedirect({from "...", to: "..."})` on my pages, and using the meta as suggested.

My .md file's frontmatter looks like this (obviously an oversimplified example):

```
---
title: My blog post
author: me
redirect_from: /resources/blogs/blog-123
---
File content of the blog text bla bla bla bla
```

So I am attempting to read that with this query:

```
graphql(`
{
  allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fields {
          slug                // the filepath
          realPath            // a custom field that i actually use to URL
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
          author
          redirect_from
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`)
```

So this is working, perfectly.... under one very simple condition and that would be:
I need to write a path that is not the **ACTUAL** path to the file. The idea is to redirect users:

**FROM:** www.mysite.com/resourecs/blog/blog-123

**TO:** www.mysite.com/blog-123

But as soon as I type in the real file path into the `redirect_from` field in my frontmatter, I get an empty string `""` as a result of the query. If I write random gibberish, it returns the proper string.

I've since concluded that the reason for this is because I am writing a path like so:
`/resources/blogs/blog-123/` and it gets evaluated. But I do not know what evaluates it, how, or can I somehow stop it and just retrieve the string?

Comment: As a workaround, escaping your `redirect_from` might help? For example `#/resources/blogs/blog-123/#`. Unescape it when you need it.

Comment: Yeh that is how I did it in the end but I'd like to do it clean if at all possible, anyone?